# Existence of an element of order $p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian finite non trivial group and $p$ a prime number which devises o(G). We denote $H$ the set of non trivial subgroups of $G$.

Could you please help me to show that if there exists $M\in H$ such that $p$ devises $o(M)$  then there exists $g\in G$ of order $p$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean that $p$ divides $o(M)$?

Comment: yes i mean that p divides o(M)

Answer (score 1):

This is true by [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)): If $p$ divides the order of $G$ then $G$ contains an element of order $p$. You don't need the hypothesis that $M$ exists, and I'm not sure that assumption allows for a simpler proof anyways.

Comment: i want to prove the theorem by answering some questions , can you help me ?

Comment: @Sam For a proof see the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

We know that there exist $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $o(M) = pq$, we also know that $o(M), p > 0$ then $q >0$. Since H is non-trivial, there exists $m \in M \setminus\{e\}$ such that $o(m) \neq q$. If $q =1$ take  $g=m$ and if $q>1$ take $g = m^q$
\begin{equation*}
g^p = m^{pq} = m^{o(M)} = e.
\end{equation*}
This implies that $o(g)$ divides $p$ but $p$ is prime then $o(g) = 1$ or $o(g) = p$ but if $o(g) = 1$ then $m^q = e$ which is not possible due to the choice of $q$. Therefore $o(g) = p$.

Comment: i didn't understand why did you choose only the two cases  for q=1 and q>1

Comment: Because $o(M), p >0$ then $ q $ is a positive integer